# Understood what you said/ have understood what you have said

Tags: past-tense, present-perfect

If a teacher is talking to me and what should I say between:

- I understood what you said
- I have understood what you have said

Answer (score 0):

I understood what you said to me yesterday/last week.

I have understood what you have (just) said to me.

Couldn't be easier.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say either of those things; to me the idiomatic choice would be "I **understand** what you said".

I would say this because

- the understanding is still present
- the speaking is in the past